# Gruntfile string Negation

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

This should hopefully be a quick answer:

Given the following folder structure:

```
├── public
│   ├── app
|   |   ├── Folder A
|   |   |  ├──something.js   
    .
    .OTHER FOLDERS @ the app level
    .
    .

|   ├── libs
|   │   ├── libJS files here
```

Inside the `initConfig` I'm just trying to set up some variables for a task.

```
src: {
    js: [ 'public/**/*.js', '!public/**/*.spec.js', '!public/libs/', '!public/min/' ],
    libs: ['public/libs/*.js'],
```

What I want in english is for `<%= src.js %>` to be all the js files under the `public` folder minus the `libs` folder and the `min` folder but the above appears to select them all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore all files in the `libs` and `min` folders:

`js: [ 'public/**/*.js', '!public/**/*.spec.js', '!public/libs/**/*', '!public/min/**/*' ]`

Comment: I just figured it out myself as well... Thanks though mystery user ;)